# How do i calculate the average 3 highest values in histogram by logic?

Tags: c#

Not in C# but by thinking.

For example I have a bimtap wich is 4X4 pixels means the histogram size will be 16.

Now I have for example 10 colors from 0 to 9

And lets say once the bitmap image is black so all the pixels on the 0 color so on 0 I'll have 16 pixels.

Second example on color 0 I have three pixels on color 1 I have one pixel on color 2 I have four pixels on color 4 two pixels on color five three pixels on colors 6,7 and 9 on each one I have one pixel.

Now how do I calculate the highest three values. If I just look on it as I drawed it on a paper here its clear that color 0 , 2 and 5 are the three highest.

But how do I calculate it simple by algorithm ?

Or if all the pixels are on color 0 so how the calculation will be ? What will be the result of the three highest values if any ?

The idea is to use the histogram of the bitmap 4x4 example to calculate the three highest values.

Since the histogram already can fix them in the right order it should be easy to use it to calculate the three highest values.

Another thing:

If I got it right. The histogram size always will be the width*height of the bitmap size ?

For example if I have bitmap which is 4x4 pixels so the histogram size will be 16.

If it was 5x6 the histogram size is 30.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
int[] Histogram = new int[10];
foreach(pixel p in bitmap)
{
    histogram[p.color]++;
}
Array.Sort(Histogram);
Console.WriteLine(Histogram[0]);
Console.WriteLine(Histogram[1]);
Console.WriteLine(Histogram[2]);
```